# How to import to module using terragrunt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

So I'm having a hard time trying to [import into module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-module) when using a third-party module via terragrunt.

My terragrunt.hcl file is as follows

```
locals {
  environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))
  env = local.environment_vars.locals.environment
}

terraform {
  source = "git::git@github.com:cloudposse//terraform-aws-elasticsearch.git//?ref=0.26.0"
}

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

I was trying to import by using

```
terragrunt import module.terraform-aws-elasticsearch.aws_elasticsearch_domain.default elasticsearch
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Error: Import to non-existent module

module.terraform-aws-elasticsearch is not defined in the configuration. Please add configuration for this module before importing into it.

[terragrunt] 2021/01/25 15:23:26 Hit multiple errors:
exit status 1
```

So I'm wondering what's the proper module name or if that's even possible to do with Terragrunt.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you remove the `module.` in `terragrunt import module.terraform-aws-elasticsearch.aws_elasticsearch_domain.default elasticsearch`?

Comment: Run the `plan` command to see each resource that would be created and the "address" of each. You then use the "address" of the `aws_elasticsearch_domain` in your `import` command.